# Python Kivy write/read file to SD card

Tags: android, python, ios, kivy, sd-card

By using Python and Kivy I want to write a file to the (virtual) SD card of the user's phone and also read this file again in a different function. Since Android, IOS and Windows Phone probably have different paths to the SD card, it seems like using 'plyer' is a good idea. **How** do I **write/read** a **file** to/of the **SD card**?

Comment: No iOS devices have SD card slots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Path to SD card

```
from jnius import autoclass  # SDcard Android

# Get path to SD card Android
try:
    Environment = autoclass('android.os.Environment')
    sdpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

# Not on Android
except:
    sdpath = App.get_running_app().user_data_dir
```

user_data_dir also works on Android, but it relies on a /sdcard symlink which is becoming outdated. I don't know for IOS or Windows Phone though.

#### Copy to SD card

```
import shutil

sdpathfile = os.path.join(sdpath, 'filename')
shutil.copyfile(os.path.join('folder', 'filename2'), sdpathfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Kivy's [user_data_dir](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.user_data_dir) to return the path to the directory of the user's file system.

Then use Kivy's [storage](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.storage.html) to store data to a file in the directory.

Comment: I was told user_data_dir only worked on PC, but indeed it works. Should just have tried. Code: sdpath = App.get_running_app().user_data_dir

Comment: Kivy IRC: This works, but /sdcard symlink is becoming outdated, so you shouldn't rely on this.